# crlibm.h no such file while installing pyinterval

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install pyinterval but running into this issue.I am trying to install this in my own virtual env. Also including the log below

```
Running setup.py install for pyinterval
Running command /home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/build/pyinterval/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hJmNF8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/include/site/python2.7
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval
copying interval/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval
copying interval/imath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval
copying interval/fpu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval
copying ./LICENSE -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval
running build_ext
building 'crlibm' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/crlibm/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ext/crlibmmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext/crlibmmodule.o
ext/crlibmmodule.c:7:20: fatal error: crlibm.h: No such file or directory
 #include "crlibm.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/build/pyinterval/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hJmNF8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jibin/Desktop/chef/env/include/site/python2.7:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval

copying interval/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval

copying interval/imath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval

copying interval/fpu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval

copying ./LICENSE -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/interval

running build_ext

building 'crlibm' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/crlibm/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ext/crlibmmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext/crlibmmodule.o

ext/crlibmmodule.c:7:20: fatal error: crlibm.h: No such file or directory

 #include "crlibm.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

As you can see I was able to build crlibm.h but can't seem to be able to include it.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is my os